# Multiple Javascript functions, need confirm dialog before executing any

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have three separate javascript/jquery functions, all of which fire off after the user clicks a button. One function posts to a form handler. Another function creates a new tab. And the third function grabs the id of the new tab and posts sends new information into the tab via an ajax call. They all work together and depend on one another.

I have tried many different configurations, and I cannot figure out how to properly get a confirmation dialog (e.g., "Do you want to perform this action?) to work with all three of these simultaneously. If the user clicks "yes," the process should fire. If the user clicks "no," the process should die. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: I've posted my code below. I'm sure it's really noobish, which is why I didn't post it the begin with. Trying to learn though. Thanks!

```
jQuery(".update_form").click(function(e) { // changed
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/eemcontrolpanel/process.cshtml",
                   data: jQuery(this).parent().serialize() // changed                       
                 });
            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });

jQuery(".update_form").click(function () {
                var form = jQuery(this).parents('form:first');
                title = jQuery("input[name='process']", form).val();


                $('#tt').tabs('add',{
                    title:title,
                    content:'Script starting',
                    closable:true
                    });

                    $('div.panel-body:last').attr("id","tab" + panelIds[panelIds.length - 1] + 1);

                    panelIds.push(panelIds[panelIds.length - 1] + 1);
            });



            jQuery(".update_form").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //var j = jQuery.noConflict();
                var form = jQuery(this).parents('form:first');
                var fileName = jQuery("input[name='process']", form).val();


                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                var XHR;
                var stopMe = 1;
                var isSame = 0;
                var oldhtml;    
                var tabID = "tab" + panelIds[panelIds.length - 1];


                jQuery("#"+ tabID).everyTime(1000, function (i) { 


                      if (stopMe != 2){

                        XHR = jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "/eemcontrolpanel/jobs/" + fileName + ".txt",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (html){


                                if (html === oldhtml){
                                    isSame++;

                                        if (isSame === 10){
                                            stopMe = 2;

                                            }
                                        }
                                        jQuery("#"+ tabID).html("<pre>" + html + "</pre>").scrollHeight;
                                    oldhtml = html;


                                    }                                
                                });                          
                            } else { 
                                jQuery("#"+ tabID).stopTime();
                            }
                            jQuery("#"+ tabID).css({ color: "white" });
                         });                          
                });
            });
```

**This is what I ended up doing. I basically combined all the functions into one big function.**

```
            var panelIds = new Array();                 
            panelIds.push('0');

        jQuery(".update_form").click(function (e) {

            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {                

            e.preventDefault();

            jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/eemcontrolpanel/process.cshtml",
                   data: jQuery(this).parent().serialize() // changed                       
                 });

            var form = jQuery(this).parents('form:first');
            var title = jQuery("input[name='process']", form).val();


            $('#tt').tabs('add',{
                title:title,
                content:'Script starting',
                closable:true
                });

                $('div.panel-body:last').attr("id","tab" + panelIds[panelIds.length - 1] + 1);

                panelIds.push(panelIds[panelIds.length - 1] + 1);


            //var j = jQuery.noConflict();

            var fileName = jQuery("input[name='process']", form).val();


            var XHR;
            var stopMe = 1;
            var isSame = 0;
            var oldhtml;    
            var tabID = "tab" + panelIds[panelIds.length - 1];

            //alert(tabID);    

            jQuery("#"+ tabID).everyTime(1000, function (i) { 
                //alert(stopMe);
                  //add also if stopme=false else quit/end/whatever
                  if (stopMe != 2){
                      //alert(stopMe);
                    XHR = jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/eemcontrolpanel/jobs/" + fileName + ".txt",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (html){

                                //alert(html);
                            if (html === oldhtml){
                                isSame++;
                                //alert(isSame);
                                    if (isSame === 10){
                                        stopMe = 2;
                                        //alert(stopMe);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    jQuery("#"+ tabID).html("<pre>" + html + "</pre>").scrollHeight;
                                oldhtml = html;

                                //alert(oldhtml);
                                }                                
                            });                          
                        } else { 
                            jQuery("#"+ tabID).stopTime();
                        }
                        jQuery("#"+ tabID).css({ color: "white" });
                     });                          


            } else {

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? A little code goes a long way to explain a situation.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp should suffice for your purposes. Can you please post an example of your code and where you encounter a problem?

Comment: If the three act in sequence you should put one into the `complete` callback of the previous one... Sorry it may sounds a bit naive but without some more information it's not easy to pinpoint the problem...

Comment: chain it with `then()` method of promise interface returned by each ajax request http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: But please, POST relevant code in question!

Comment: I posted my code. Sorry I didn't at first. I didn't think I would need to, but I will remember next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
Function onButtonPush(){
    if(confirm('confirm message')){
         function1();
         function2();
         function3();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution. That doesn't seem to work. I posted my code above in case that helps you understand my situation.

Comment: Looks to me like your using annonymous functions defined directly in event listeners.  Fr this to work, you'll need to split them into individual separate functions.